# How to use HttpClient using Post method?

Tags: android

How to use HttpClient using Post method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See a docs on [DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) class and [HttpPost](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) class

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://your.site/your/service");
// set some headers if needed
post.addHeader(....);
// and an eclosed entity to send
post.setEntity(....);
// send a request and get response (if needed)
InputStream responseStream = client.execute(post).getEntity().getContent();
```

Comment: sir i implement this code but it shows me nothing in Output. I want to accees this "http://www.antikvarlden.se/antikguiden-json.aspx"

Comment: How are you getting the output? Are you checking on server-side?

Answer (score 2):

here you can get an good example [Executing a HTTP POST Request with HttpClient](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)